# css: containing random positioned images within browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to contain all my randomly positioned images within it's 100% wrap, the images are positioned randomly on page load, but as I've set the wrap to overflow: hidden some images are cut off. Is it possible to containing all the images within the wrap while also not overlapping the images?
Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdxZL/2/ 
HTML:

```
<div id="wrap" style="width: 100%; height: auto; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; overflow: hidden;">

<div id="images">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #images
    {
        left: 0; top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #images img
    {
        padding: 10px;
        position:relative;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#images img").each(
function(intIndex) {

var l = Math.floor(Math.random() * $("#images").width());
var t = Math.floor(Math.random() * $("#images").height());

$(this).css("margin-left", l);
$(this).css("margin-top", t);

}

);
});
```

Comment: You'll need to add a check to make sure that [left + img.width] is less than the parent's calculated width, and the same for [top + img.height] vs parent's calculated height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
#images img
{
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: this just makes the images 100% width, I want the images to stay at 200px, but to stay contained within the bound of it's parent div (so you aren't being shown half an image)